# Awk script piping changes apparent execution order

Tags: awk, scripting, piping

Following is a segment of my script:

```
END{
    for (key in data) {
        print key" "data[key]|"sort -k 2n";
    }
    print "something or other"
}
```

The problem is, that the console output first shows the second print output, and then shows the result of the print outputs piped through sort in the for loop.

Tried cruly braces to no avail.
I have no idea how to even google about this problem, how does sort collect what it should sort? How can I direct it better?

Edit: Just had a moment of realization, the problem is not that it catches the last print, but that it actually gets executed after the last print, despite being called earlier.

Comment: Look up `close()` in the awk man page. If you need more help then [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the close() function suggested by Ed Morton.

For details about close(), I found https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html to be useful.

The correct code segment thus became:

```
END{
    for (key in data) {
        print key" "data[key]|"sort -k 2n";
    }
    close("sort -k 2n");
    print "something or other";
}
```

this way, it correctly prints out the sorted output from the for loop, and only after that prints out the last print output called after the loop.

Comment: Don't use the same hard-coded string for the execution and the close, define a variable like `cmd="sort -k -2n"` and use that in both locations.